# How to get title, message and buttons of windows message box/alert/confirmation massage

Tags: c#, windows, testing, specflow

I'm testing a windows application with c# specflow. I need to close a window and then it opens up a confirmation dialog. I want to verify the title, and message and need to click on the buttons(Yes/No) of the confirmation dialog. (like the image below)

[image]

Current code for closing the window

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);


private static void CloseDialog()
{
    var handle = FindWindow(null, "Give your window caption/title here");
    SetForegroundWindow(handle);

    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("%{F4}");
}
```

any idea?

Comment: Does your code not work?

Comment: Typically we use `driver.SwitchTo().Alert()` to get a handle on the current alert box, confirmation dialog, or input dialog.

Comment: And I'm just realizing you are not using Selenium. Sorry about that. Which UI automation framework are you using?

Comment: Not using any automation framework. And I tried with Selenium. It does not work because this message box is WPF. Selenium cannot work with WPF